# How to add a column with buttons to a bootstrap table populated by data from MySQL DB?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap table that displays data loaded from MySQL DB. I want to add a column with buttons so that it would look similar to this image.

[image]

However, I don't know how to add buttons into my script. When I "manually" create a table, I can easily do this:

```
<td>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit </a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete </a>
</td>
```

But when I populate table with the data from DB, the logic of creating table changes. This is my code:

```
<table  id="table"
   data-show-columns="true"
   data-height="460">
</table>
```

Script for loading data (I do not provide `list.php` because it just contains PHP script for connecting to DB and submitting SELECT queries):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   var $table = $('#table');
         $table.bootstrapTable({
            url: 'include/list.php',
            search: true,
            pagination: true,
            buttonsClass: 'primary',
            showFooter: true,
            minimumCountColumns: 2,
            columns: [{
                field: 'id',
                title: 'ID',
                sortable: true,
            },{
                field: 'creation_date',
                title: 'Date',
                sortable: true,
            },{
                field: 'latitude',
                title: 'Latitude',
                sortable: true,

            },  ],

         });

</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked out this documentation? http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/

Comment: You might also want to look into datatables (https://datatables.net)

Comment: @EmirhanÖzlen: Yes, but I cannot figure out how to add a column with buttons. It seems to me that doing something like this is an easier option: http://www.codingcage.com/2016/09/bootstrap-modal-with-dynamic-mysql-data.html, but it means that I should change the whole approach.

Answer (score 1):

It is all you need

```
$('#table tbody tr').append('<td><a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit </a><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete </a></td>');
```

Comment: Thanks. If I want to add onclick events, I can simply edit `append`?

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Where exactly should I place this code?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem myself using the following approach:

```
    <?php
      include_once 'include/connect_db.php';

      $query = "SELECT * FROM base;";
      $result = execute_query($query);

      $list = array();
      while ($b = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $list[] = $b;
      }
    ?>

<table id="table-b" class="table table-striped projects">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th style="width: 1%">#</th>
    <th style="width: 10%">ID de base/th>
    <th>Fecha de registro</th>
    <th>Latitud</th>
    <th>Longitud</th>
    <th style="width: 20%"></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <?php foreach ($list as $row):?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['ID'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['creation_date'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['latitude'];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['longitude'];?></td>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit </a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <?php endforeach;?>
</tbody>
</table>


        <script>
             $(document).ready(function(){
                      $('#table-b').dataTable({
                      "sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
                      "aaSorting":[[0, "asc"]],
                      "bJQueryUI":true
                      });

                      hideLoading();

             });
        </script>
```